# What should I do to see the number of outgoing tokens in the transaction hash?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

I will need the following data of the outgoing transaction with a transaction hash given by the user:
sender,
recipient,
transferred token amount.

I was able to get sender and recepient data with getTransactionReceipt function using web3 library.

But I don't know which token is sent and how much is the amount how can I get it? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry this is not an answer per-se, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

To see such information, you can check the transaction on a block explorer like bscscan or etherscan depending on the network or you can use a tool like [tenderly](https://tenderly.co)

Comment: yes i look bscscan etc. but I need to do this control with code.

Comment: Check out [Adam Kipnis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48012819/8086938) and [Tomer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982140/8086938) answers they both cover how that can be achieved. They did a better job than I ever will

Comment: I'm happy to be of some help.